# High low Omaha question

Tags: omaha-hi-lo

With the board showing A2345 would a hand consisting of 67 win both the high and low? Or would a hand holding  A2 in it win the low? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For both your high and your low hand you must use 2 cards from your hand and 3 cards from the board. With 76 you have 34567 for the high and A2367 for the low. With A2 you have A2345 for the high and A2345 for the low.

So 76 does not have the better low than A2. A2, A3, A4, A5, 32, 42, 52, 43 and 54 all have the nut low.

Comment: And depending on the suit of the cards, 67 might not win high if there is a flush possible on the board.